# Remember Me in Seam 3

Tags: jsf-2, seam3

How can I use the remember me feature of seam security 3???

I try the seam 2 way but it does not work...
here my components.xml... not sure if this file is used in seam 3

```
   <security:jpa-token-store token-class="org.jboss.seam.example.seamspace.AuthenticationToken" />
<security:remember-me mode="autoLogin"/>
 <event type="org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn">

<action execute="#{redirect.captureCurrentView}"/>

<action execute="#{identity.tryLogin()}"/>
```

```
<action execute="#{redirect.returnToCapturedView}"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your error? What happens that lets you know it doesn't work?

Comment: No data is write to the token table

Comment: Did you use that feature Justin? @JustinSatyr

Comment: I didn't test this, I was only asking for your benefit so people who saw this later could help you more easily.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://community.jboss.org/thread/178998 the RemeberMe is not be integrated seam-security-3.1, but the class is already [prepared](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.seam.security/seam-security/3.1.0.Final/org/jboss/seam/security/RememberMe.java#RememberMe).

The known RememberMe from [Seam2](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/security.html#d0e8871) is available in two modes:

- The first mode allows the username to be stored in the user's browser as a cookie, and leaves the entering of the password up to the browser (many modern browsers are capable of remembering passwords).
- The second mode supports the storing of a unique token in a cookie, and allows a user to authenticate automatically upon returning to the site, without having to provide a password.

Fortunately it's not hard to implement a workaround for the first mode. After a successful login you can set a cookie:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addResponseCookie("cookieName", "myToken", null);
```

Then make sure your own `CookieBean` is invoked before the login

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{cookieBean.dummy}"/>
<h:form id="fLogin">
  <h:inputText value="#{credentials.username}"/>
  <h:inputSecret value="#{credentials.password}" redisplay="true"/>
  <h:commandButton value="LOGIN" action="#{identity.login}"/>
</h:form>
```

In your `CookieBean` you can check if your cookie is available, map a provided token to a username and then fill the username in your form.

```
@Named @SessionScoped
public class CookieBean implements Serializable
{
  @Inject Credentials credentials;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  { 
    Map<String, Object> cookies = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                        getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap();
    // Check if you cookie is available
    // Do some stuff with your cookie
    // Cookie cookie = (Cookie) cookies.get("cookieName");
    credentials.setUsername("myUserName");
  }

  public boolean getDummy() {return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seam 3 doesn't use components.xml to configure components/beans.

I don't think Seam Security 3 (as of 3.0.0.Final) has a built-in 'rememberMe' functionality.